# PHP Include class to my mini framework - error

Tags: php, include, fatal-error

Quick question. I have mvc (my mini framework ;) ) for eduction.

https://github.com/aras123/MiniFramework

If I create file test.php in root base (for example).

**test.php**

```
<?php 
class Example {
    public function __construct() {
    echo 'This is example!';
    }
}
```

And in my framework create action for IndexController and want include and run class

**Application/Controller/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;
use Framework\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller {
    public function _init() {
    }

    public function IndexAction() {
        require 'test.php'; //path is ok
                $aaa = new Example(); //is error 
    }
```

**error message:**

```
Fatal error: Class 'Application\Controller\Example' not found in
/Application/Controller/IndexController.php on line ...
```

Comment: Have you *included* the file?

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at the `__autoload` function you have in index.php and check to see if its being called for Example, and if it is, what file its looking for. Check to make sure its looking in the right place

Comment: As Jason said, Have you included the file? Else, try to change $aaa = new Example(); to $aaa = new Example;

Comment: @briosheje, there is no difference between `new Example()` and `new Example`

Comment: Example seems to have no namespace, so use `new \Example;` (assuming its really included as pointed out above)

Comment: Here is a suggestion: avoid that thing. It's filled with bad practices and misinformation.

Answer (score 1):

They way your autoloader works, its not picking up the file you created. Theres two solutions here, either you have an include at the top of your controller

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;
require __DIR__ . '/../../test.php';
// ...
```

Or, you move `test.php` to `Application\Controller` and rename it to `Example.php`

I would suggest the latter

Comment: all i can really say is take a look at your autoloader, and how it works

Answer (score 0):

Yes! This is good code:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;
use Framework\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller {
    public function _init() {
    }

    public function IndexAction() {
        require 'test.php'; //path is ok
                $aaa = new \Example(); //now is ok!
    }
```